# Only 5 cars out of 1000 cars pay the exact amount of toll.Compute the probability that out of 2000 cars none will pay toll?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

My Work:

let p represent favourable number of cases => 5/1000=0.005

let q represent non favourable number of cases => 995/1000=0.995

Given,

We are given sample of =≥ 2000 cars

So applying Binomial Distribution,

P(X=0)=nCx * p^x * q^n-x

2000c0 * 0.005^0 * 0.995^2000

I am getting my final answer very minute and i doubt its incorrect.Also it would be a great help if someone can guide me whether binomial ,hypergeometric or poisson distribution ways will be optimal to solve this problem!

Comment: Your method looks fine to me.  :)

Comment: Thank you but still i think for calculating none of people giving exact amount of toll should be more around 0.89….. but i am getting around 0.00004*10^-5 ..

Comment: If the probability that any given driver pays the toll exactly is $p=0.005$ and the payments are independent events, then the probability that none of the 2000 drivers pays the exact toll is simply $$(1-p)^{2000}\approx 4.42753\cdot 10^{-5}.$$  That seems correct to me.  (Hopefully, I am correct because I did teach math for a few years.)

Comment: @NikolaiRomanovBelliovichksky To approximate the binomial distribution you can use the poisson distribution. Nevertheless, practically the probability is $0.$

Comment: Ok thank you so much!